# WPF C#: Setting background color of a WPF app not setting fully

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a WPF app (WindowStyle="None" hence no default windows buttons like exit, maximize, minimize)

It doesn't set the color (in my case, it's black) to the entire frame:
[image: Error]

As you can see, there is a bit of white gap. (It's not a margin, I tested for this).

```
<Window x:Class="FancyGUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="340"
        Background="Black">

</Window>
```

Comment: have you tried setting `ResizeMode="NoResize"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `ResizeMode="NoResize"` in your window, otherwise there's a title bar shown (empty in your case), even if you set `WindowStyle="None"`.

- With `WindowStyle="None"` only:

[image]

<sup>*(notice the blue "gap" as you call it on top... that's your white gap, just that my theme is blue)*</sup>

- With `ResizeMode="NoResize"`:

[image]

<sup>*(no gap, but can't resize the window now)*</sup>

- Or if you still want it to be resized (have the resize grip on it), but not show that title bar, set `AllowsTransparency="True"` and `ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"`:

[image]

<sup>*(notice the grip for resizing on bottom right)*</sup>

Note that having `AllowsTransparency=true` may have side effects. If any of those side effects is a problem to you, you can implement the resizing yourself by creating your own (black in your case) border and send the drag/resize messages. Expand on whether you need this or not and I'll show you how.

Answer (score 3):

I'm noticing that the typical chrome is removed around the window.

I recreated the window with the code you provided and I see this:
[image: black background with window chrome]

Is there a resource file being referenced that may be affecting the window?

Also, you have Live Visual Tree running.  Try clicking the middle button and then try clicking on the white bar.  If you can select it, you should see it selected in the VS Live Visual Tree window.

[image: activate live visual tree]

***Edit...***
After seeing Jcl's post about the ResizeMode="NoResize" I gave it a try.
Sure enough, that's the secret.

[image]

Thanks Jcl!

Comment: Yep, btw, the difference about your window chrome and the OP's, is that he's using Windows 10... Windows 10 "tool windows" with a resizing border look like that... you are probably running win7 or 8, which looks like in your screenshots (no titlebar and a shiny aero chrome on the border)